# Every affine subset $A$ of $R^n$ is spanned by a finite subset.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Every affine subset $A$ of $R^n$ is spanned by a finite subset. (Hint: Choose a maximal affine independent subset of A.)

I'm not really sure how to start this.  I would assume something related to Zorn's lemma but after choosing a maximal (ordered by set inclusion?) affine independent subset of $A$ I'm really not sure.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A maximal independent subset $S$ of $A$ much also span $A$, for if it didn't, we could pick some $x\in A\backslash \mathrm{span}(S)$, and so $S\cup\{x\}$ would be an independent subset of $A$ with $S\subsetneq S\cup\{x\}$, contradicting the maximality of $S$.

Comment: @Florence How do you know that we can choose an $\{x\} \in A$ \ $\text{span}(S)$ such that $S \cup \{x\}$ is affine independent?  Why can we guarantee that we can make $S \cup \{x\}$ affine independent?

Comment: @Florence I can't figure a way to prove this, can you explain to me why this is true?

Comment: The proof is essentially the same as for vector spaces. If $x$ is not in the span of $S$, and if $S$ is linearly/affinely independent, then $S\cup \{x\}$ is linearly/affinely independent. For suppose $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, and say we have $a_0(x-x_n)+a_1(x-x_1)+a_2(x-x_2)+...+a_{n-1}(x-x_{n-1})=0$. If $a_0 = 0$, then all other coefficients are $0$, since $S$ is independent. Otherwise, if $a_0 \neq 0$, then we see that $x$ is in the affine span of $S$. Thus, if $x\notin \mathrm{span}(S)$, then all coefficients are zero, and so $S\cup\{x\}$ is independent.

Comment: How does $a_0=0 \Rightarrow $ the other $a_i$'s $=0$?  $S$ being affine independent implies that there's an $x_j \in S$ such that for all $\{a_0, ..., a_{n-1}\}$ we have $a_0(x_1-x_j) + ... + a_{n-1}(x_n-x_j) = 0 \Rightarrow a_i=0$, but each $x_i \in S$ whereas $x \notin S$.

Comment: @Florence Would you mind explaining why this is true?  I'm self learning this and any help would be helpful.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake, I should have made my equation $a_0(x-x_n)+a_1(x_1-x_n)+...+a_{n-1}(x_{n-1}-x_n)=0$.

Comment: So since $x$ isn't in the span, it implies that $a_0$ has to be $0$ which implies the rest are $0$.  Thank you, that makes sense.  If you want to submit that as an answer I'll give you the points.

Comment: That's alright, glad I could help :)